# SEO Optimization Error, improper crawling or improper indexing

Tags: optimization, indexing, seo, search-engine

i have a blog build in wordpress, And my domain name is like example.com (i can't give you the original name, because some times the editors will mark this question as SPAM :( , and if any one really want to check directly from my site will add at the end of the question.)

**http://example.com** and the blog name is **http://example.com/articles/**

and the **sitemap.xml** is available in **http://example.com/sitemap.xml**

Google daily visit my site and all my new articles were crawled, if i search the "articles title + example.com " will get the search result from the google , its my site. but the heading is not the actual one. its getting from another article's data. 
(i think can give you a sample search query, please don't take this as a spam)
**Installing Go Language in Ubuntu+tutorboy**  - But this will list with proper title after a long title :(, I think now you understood what i am facing ... please help me to find out why this happens.

**Edit:**
How can i improve my SEO with wordpress?

Comment: Agreed, not programming related. Ask a specific code question about a WP plug in that offers this result and its a different story.

Answer (score 0):

When I search that query I don't get the page "Installing Go...", I get the "PHP header types" article, which has the above text on the page (links at the right). So the titles showing in Google *are* correct.

Google has obviously not crawled that page yet since it's quite new. Give it time, especially if your site is new and/or unpopular.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I need to make clear:

Google crawled your site `on 24 Nov 2009 12:01:01 GMT`, so needless to say Google actually does not visit your site(blog)everyday.

When I queried the phrase you provided, the results are right. There are two url relates to your site. One is home page of your blog, another is the page that is (more closely)related to your query. The reason is the query phrase is directly related to the page of `tutorboy.com/articles/php/use-php-functions-in-javascript.html`, however, in your home page there are still some related keywords. That is the reason why Google presents two pages on the result page.

Your second question is hard to answer since it needs a complicated answer. Still, the following steps are crucial to your SEO.

1. Unique and good content. Content is king, and it is the subject that remains consistent in the whole time while another elements are changing with the evolving of search engine technology.  Also keep your site content fresh.
2. Back links. Part of the reason that Google does not visit your site after your updating your site is your site lacks enough back links.
3. Good structure. Properly use those tags like`<t>`, `<description>`,`<alt>`etc.
4. Using web analysts tools like Google Analysts. It free, and you can see lot of things that you missed.
5. Most importantly, grabbing some SEO books or spending couple of minutes everyday to read some SEO articles.

Good Luck,